# Stripe No such payment_intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe's demo custom form to work on my website. I am not using a local server. Everything I am doing is on my webhost.

I have tried the prebuilt page and it works fine, I am getting payment on my stripe account from those. When I use their custom payment form, I get an error.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

I copied the code they provided on the Custom Payment Flow section, however when I go to try and pay, it shows me an error on the page
"No such payment_intent: 'pi_1IAXXXXXXXXX'".
On the stripe account, the payment shows as incomplete and has this message

```
The PaymentIntent requires a payment method
Set an existing payment method on the PaymentIntent or have the customer enter a new payment method.
Learn more
```

I tried going through the code but I am not experienced so I do not understand.

I tried a solution provided here by trying to provide my accountID in the stripe variable as such

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxx', {stripeAccount: 'acct_xxxxx'});
```

But I was still getting the same error.
I double checked my keys to make sure they were the same and everything is fine there.

I am not sure what could be wrong.

These are the files that I have, they are exactly the same as the demo provided on their site so I have no idea what could be wrong.

I downloaded the Stripe API and uploaded it to my webhost. I am using

```
require 'stripe-php/stripe-php/init.php';
```

instead of the code provided in the demo

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

because I am not using composer.

cpf_create.php (changed the secret key for this post)

```
<?php
require 'stripe-php/stripe-php/init.php';

// This is your real test secret API key.
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_XXXXXXX');
function calculateOrderAmount(array $items): int {
  // Replace this constant with a calculation of the order's amount
  // Calculate the order total on the server to prevent
  // customers from directly manipulating the amount on the client
  return 1400;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
try {
  // retrieve JSON from POST body
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
  $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),
    'currency' => 'usd',
  ]);
  $output = [
    'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
  ];
  echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
  http_response_code(500);
  echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

cpf_client.js

```
// A reference to Stripe.js initialized with your real test publishable API key.
var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_XXXXXXXXX");
// The items the customer wants to buy
var purchase = {
  items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }]
};
// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
fetch("/cpf_create.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
})
  .then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    var style = {
      base: {
        color: "#32325d",
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
        fontSize: "16px",
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#32325d"
        }
      },
      invalid: {
        fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
        color: "#fa755a",
        iconColor: "#fa755a"
      }
    };
    var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
    // Stripe injects an iframe into the DOM
    card.mount("#card-element");
    card.on("change", function (event) {
      // Disable the Pay button if there are no card details in the Element
      document.querySelector("button").disabled = event.empty;
      document.querySelector("#card-error").textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
    });
    var form = document.getElementById("payment-form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Complete payment when the submit button is clicked
      payWithCard(stripe, card, data.clientSecret);
    });
  });
// Calls stripe.confirmCardPayment
// If the card requires authentication Stripe shows a pop-up modal to
// prompt the user to enter authentication details without leaving your page.
var payWithCard = function(stripe, card, clientSecret) {
  loading(true);
  stripe
    .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: card
      }
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Show error to your customer
        showError(result.error.message);
      } else {
        // The payment succeeded!
        orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
      }
    });
};
/* ------- UI helpers ------- */
// Shows a success message when the payment is complete
var orderComplete = function(paymentIntentId) {
  loading(false);
  document
    .querySelector(".result-message a")
    .setAttribute(
      "href",
      "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments/" + paymentIntentId
    );
  document.querySelector(".result-message").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
};
// Show the customer the error from Stripe if their card fails to charge
var showError = function(errorMsgText) {
  loading(false);
  var errorMsg = document.querySelector("#card-error");
  errorMsg.textContent = errorMsgText;
  setTimeout(function() {
    errorMsg.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
};
// Show a spinner on payment submission
var loading = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
};
```

cpf_checkout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Accept a card payment</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A demo of a card payment on Stripe" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cpf_global.css" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="/cpf_client.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Display a payment form -->
    <form id="payment-form">
      <div id="card-element"><!--Stripe.js injects the Card Element--></div>
      <button id="submit">
        <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
        <span id="button-text">Pay</span>
      </button>
      <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
      <p class="result-message hidden">
        Payment succeeded, see the result in your
        <a href="" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to pay again.
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any luck on this issue? I have the same problem and it's drving me cray-cray

Comment: unfortunately not, I started using their premade page after they updated some stuff as it meets my needs.

Answer (score 0):

“No such...” errors are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account).

Comment: I did check the API keys and I only have one account. I am simply copying the exact code they have provided on their website and following it. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: If you write into Support, they can look into the details for you: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of that :s thanks!